# How is Mathematica minimizing correlation exactly with linear constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I made a random data matrix as

```
data = Table[Random[], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
```

In my case it was
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0.951203 & 0.546669 & 0.86928 & 0.00281753 & 0.306743 \\
 0.823344 & 0.117588 & 0.530483 & 0.777849 & 0.440718 \\
 0.109126 & 0.0686256 & 0.516334 & 0.460716 & 0.395735 \\
 0.254902 & 0.0376569 & 0.0648415 & 0.699014 & 0.373885 \\
 0.75997 & 0.995759 & 0.923424 & 0.498251 & 0.808767 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I understand how Mathematica is able to solve the optimization problem below, thanks to the theory behind [canonical correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation):

```
Minimize[
 Correlation[Sum[a[i] data[[;; , i]], {i, 1, 4}], data[[;; , -1]]], 
 Table[a[i], {i, 4}]]
```

What I am not sure is how is it possible to get an exact solution with `Minimize` when I add linear/affine constraints

```
Minimize[{Correlation[Sum[a[i] data[[;; , i]], {i, 1, 4}], 
   data[[;; , -1]]], a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] > 0.1, a[2] - a[3] < 1}, 
 Table[a[i], {i, 4}]]
```

**I am interested to learn how Mathematica is doing the optimization under the hood for the constrained problem, because I would like to use the same method in Python for greater speed**. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute some variables a[i] according to conditions with other variables b[i].

I rationalize data to get reliable conditions to show here.

```
data = Table[Random[], {i, 5}, {j, 5}] // Rationalize[#, 10^-5] &

data = {{254/763, 219/340, 83/85, 55/166, 260/383}, {50/183, 207/263, 67/135,
   179/380, 116/275}, {32/195, 46/205, 123/211, 95/251, 215/
  633}, {108/235, 747/971, 255/274, 271/376, 325/366}, {89/215, 99/
  223, 14/207, 124/407, 53/654}}

vars1 = Table[a[i], {i, 4}];

cor = Correlation[Sum[a[i] data[[;; , i]], {i, 1, 4}], 
           data[[;; , -1]]];

cond1 = a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] > 0.1 && a[2] - a[3] < 1 // 
           Rationalize

NMinimize[cor, vars1]

(*   {-1., {a[1] -> -31900.6, a[2] -> -8755.95, a[3] -> -57342.8, 
      a[4] -> -40593.6}}   *)

nmin1 = NMinimize[{cor, cond1}, vars1]

(*   {-0.835107, {a[1] -> 11.1137, a[2] -> -4.2961, a[3] -> -5.2961, 
                  a[4] -> -1.42148}}   *)
```

Conditions satisfied (sometimes other methods give better result)

```
cond1[[All, 1]] /. nmin1[[2]]

(*   0.1 && 1.   *)

NMinimize[{cor, cond1}, vars1, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]

(*   {-0.835107, {a[1] -> 11.1131, a[2] -> -4.29585, a[3] -> -5.29585, 
  a[4] -> -1.42139}}   *)
```

Reduce condtions to solve for some varialbles.

```
Reduce[cond1, vars1, Reals]

(*   a[3] > -1 + a[2] && a[4] > 1/10 (1 - 10 a[1] - 10 a[2] - 10 a[3])   *)
```

My experience is, you get better results, if you alter the sequence of variables a[i] until you get one a[i] > ... and one a[j]< ...

```
Reduce[cond1, {a[4], a[3], a[2], a[1]}, Reals]

(*   a[2] < 1 + a[3] && a[1] > 1/10 (1 - 10 a[2] - 10 a[3] - 10 a[4])   *)
```

Now substitute b[i] with conditions b[i] > 0 or if you don't want to impose any condition on b[i] for calculation minimum with the phyton-minimization routine, substitute b[i]^2.

```
subst1 = {a[2] -> 1 + a[3] - b[2], 
          a[1] -> 1/10 (1 - 10 a[2] - 10 a[3] - 10 a[4]) + b[1]};

subst2 = {a[2] -> 1 + a[3] - b[2]^2, 
          a[1] -> 1/10 (1 - 10 a[2] - 10 a[3] - 10 a[4]) + b[1]^2};
```

Attention, substitute repeated with `//. subst1`

```
NMinimize[{cor //. subst1, b[1] > 0 && b[2] > 0}, {b[1], b[2], a[3], a[4]}]

(*   {-0.835107, {b[1] -> 0., b[2] -> 0., a[3] -> -5.29062, 
  a[4] -> -1.41992}}   *)

NMinimize[cor //. subst2, {b[1], b[2], a[3], a[4]}]

(*   {-0.835107, {b[1] -> -4.81865*10^-8, b[2] -> 7.9381*10^-7, 
  a[3] -> -5.29455, a[4] -> -1.42104}}   *)
```